# Get user local time by ip address with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm trying to get time of day for someone visiting my site. Seems easy enough, but the tricky part is that people may be traveling from other timezones and not changing their system clock. Using the below:

```
  var d = new Date();
  var currentTime = d.getHours();
  console.log( currentTime );

  if(currentTime < 12){
    var tod = "morning";
  }else if(currentTime >= 12 && currentTime <= 17){
    var tod = "afternoon";
  }else{
    var tod = "evening";
  }
document.write("hour of day is: "+currentTime);
console.log("Time of day is: "+tod );
```

I was able to detect local system time. For example, if my clock says 7:06 AM, then the variable **currentTime** will be 7. This works based on the system clock. So if I change my time zone to Eastern, **currentTime** will be 10 instead of 7. The problem is I'd like to detect the time of day where the user is actually sitting at that moment. So if I'm on the East coast and my system clock says 7AM, I still want to show the user a 10. I want to detect the hour of day it actually is where the user is by IP address. I have found a way to collect IP address, but not sure how to use it to get the local time.

If there is another way I am also open to that as well. Thanks.

Some might suggest getting it from the server, but I am using marketing cloud and there does not appear to be a way to do it. I've used the available AmpScript functions and they do not work as I would have expected.

Comment: IP Addresses are strictly digital addresses for computers. There are services you can pay for to "geolocate" an IP address but that may not be correct and you may not be able to find a free service.

Answer (score 0):

Use any API that will respond with user's timezone. For example this one:

```
http://ip-api.com/json
```

And calculate user's time basing on it.

Comment: Michal, can you provide a bit more detail?